Unable to use object in react with useSignal
I'm using @preact/signals-react to manage state, but I'm having trouble getting the component to re-render when I update an object's property. I can see the changes when I log the value, but the component doesn't reflect these changes.
import { useSignal } from '@preact/signals-react'

function App() {
    const ob = useSignal({ x: 0 })

    setInterval(() => {
        ob.value.x = Math.random()
        console.log(ob.value)
    }, 1000)

    return <>x : {ob.value.x}</>
}

export default App

What's wrong?

Edit: I used react-app-rewired instead of CRA and it worked.

If you haven't read the instructions, you need to use the Babel plugin or add the useSignals() hook into every component. As you haven't mentioned the Babel plugin, you're probably missing it.
Edit: You also cannot assign to properties, you must assign to ob.value alone. @preact/signals-react does not, out of the box, provide deep reactivity.
ob.value = { ...ob.value, x: Math.random() };


Seems like my issue is bcoz of babel. I followed the instructions u provided and this one. But I still can't get it to work :( (Mine is a Create React App project)

Unfortunately Create React App doesn't allow you to customize the Babel configuration in any way, you'll need to use something like CRACO or eject your app. You can still use the useSignals() hook instead though, but it'll be more manual for sure.

I used react-app-rewired instead of CRA and it worked! So all I had to do was install a bunch of stuffs and set up a config-overrides.js file. And this took me a day to figure out!
